# remove view from super view from otherclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller

Hi i am having three view controllers. A,B,C firstly i am adding B under A then C under B.In C view controller When C is visible after click of a button i want to remove C from super view and also B from its super view.for removing C from B i am using following code

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

I am able to remove C from B on click of button. But how can i remove B from A from C ViewController class. So after clicking of button in C view controller both B, C must be remove & only A should be visible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding B to A and C to B means adding view of these controllers to related view controller views. Be sure that you are not pushing controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView` has a property `superview` so you can call.

```
[self.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
```

Be sure to read the documentation: [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIView_Class/index.html).

EDIT: Bear in mind that as view C is a subview of view B, this code will remove both C and B from A.

Comment: If the superview of C is B and the superview of B is A then calling `self.view.superview` in C should get you a reference to B. Calling `self.view.superview.superview` should get you a reference to A e.t.c.

Comment: I am using self.view.superview removefromsuperview in class C to remove B from A

Comment: OK I just experimented in an iOS project that I'm working on and it works fine. Make sure that `self.view.superview != nil;`

Comment: I would advise against manipulating another view controller's view hierarchy from outside. Instead, I'd add a protocol/message to the parent view controller (A) asking it to remove B. Much cleaner from an OO point of view.

Comment: What problems could arise from using this method?

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't work on iOS 7 just make sure that you're referencing the right view

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of dependency between C and B or C and A. Simply put, C needs to inform either B that it should be removed from it's superview or A that it should remove it's subview B.

You can achieve this either by a protocol or a notification

Comment: This is a bit over complex for a simple task.

Comment: RASS solution is both simpler and more elegant. Use that one

Answer (score 0):

you should use delegates. C is a view which parent is B, so it's more correct that B is the view which closes C, and the same for B, A must be the one which closes B.

In order to do that you have to implement a protocol in C and other in B, one like this:

```
@protocol ViewControllerCDelegate <NSObject>

    - (void)didSelectCloseViewC;

@end
```

And the view B have to implement this protocol, and in this method you have to close view C. Like this:

```
- (void)didSelectCloseViewC {
       [self.viewC removeFromSuperView];
}
```

And you have to repeat this process with views B and A, view B will have its protocol and view A will implement it. So in the previous method didSelectCloseViewC you will finally have this:

```
- (void)didSelectCloseViewC {
       [self.viewC removeFromSuperView];
       [self.delegate didSelecCloseViewB];
}
```

And in the view A you will implement the view B protocol like this:

```
- (void)didSelectCloseViewB {
       [self.viewB removeFromSuperView];
}
```